# URL Rewriting using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying lear to make a simple url rewrite and can't understand why is not working.

I created the file .htaccess with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^section\.php$ /how-does-it-work/ [R]
```

All i want to do is /section.php be displayed as /how-does-it-work/

i'm following a tutorial but doesn't seem to work.

Nothing seems to work… i even tried a mod_rewrite generator, i'm using GoDaddy, is there anything i should activate or something? 'cause so far i'm only dealing with the .htaccess file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using them the wrong way around. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^how-does-it-work/?$ /section.php [L]
```

Comment: Almost. Something like `/how-does-it-work/` is an SEO-style URI coming in from a browser. You want to translate it to the "real" code `/section.php` that your server can understand. Then you want `RewriteRule ^how-does-it-work/?$ /section.php`

Comment: Thanks. Changed the answer according to your input. Missed that one. +1 for spotting it.

Comment: Hey Severin, thanks for the answer but that does't work… i'm getting the page displayed but in the url says /section.php, the way i had it before didn't showed me the content but the url was /how-does-it-work/... any thoughts?

Comment: Try exchanging the [R] with the [L] I used in my answer.

Comment: Nothing seems to work… i even tried a mod_rewrite generator, i'm using GoDaddy, is there anything i should activate or something? 'cause so far i'm only dealing with the .htaccess file.

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of a least. Sorry.

Comment: [R] is to set a return code such as [R=301], and [L] marks the Last rewrite rule after a rewrite cond. You don't want either of them. So, EXACTLY what is your .htaccess , your input URI, and your desired output URI? Are you typing in the URL in all lower case? Use [NC] flag if you need case-insensitive pattern matching.